# Alternative to MediaWiki which has permission for each post/article

Tags: security, mediawiki

Is there any good replacement for MediaWiki (open source is preferable) with build in per-page access management?
I know there're plenty of extension for wiki that could do that but my client doesn't feel totally comfortable about using these.
This is a warning message from MediaWiki page that appear on SimpleSecurity extension's official homepage that scare my client when I propose the SimpleSecurity solution to him:

> If you need per-page or partial page access restrictions, you are
>   advised to install an appropriate content management package.
>   MediaWiki was not written to provide per-page access restrictions, and
>   almost all hacks or patches promising to add them will likely have
>   flaws somewhere, which could lead to exposure of confidential data. We
>   are not responsible for anything being leaked, leading to loss of
>   funds or one's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) has per-page read and edit permissions. Otherwise, DokuWiki has fewer features than MediaWiki. In particular, DokuWiki is problematic in changing page names or moving pages from one place to another. See this relatively complete [comparison](http://www.wikimatrix.org/compare/DokuWiki+MediaWiki+MoinMoin) of the two.

Comment: Eventually, we chose twiki, it written in Perl and has a fairly good access controll system which allow us to secure to the level of Workspace and post; and by users and usergroups

Answer (score 1):

On other interesting alternative that I found out is the [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org/), which is a community fork of Twiki.
If someone ever comes across this question, these are interesting resource to begin with

- My other question in Quora: https://www.quora.com/Knowledge-Management/What-is-the-best-alternative-for-Media-wiki-with-built-in-per-page-permission
- Twiki incident: http://fosiki.com/blog/2008/10/29/twiki-stops-being-open-source/
- Comparison: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/886-practical-differences-between-foswiki-and-twiki/